# Convert PDF into excel data

Tags: excel, pdf, pdf-conversion

I have a PDF which is having the below data attached as an image. How can I convert it into a tabular format as CSV/excels?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract the data from the image using `OpenCv`.
Take a look to this tutorial:
--> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/